# A Whole Screen of Errors when Installing Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I am installing Laravel to use instead of CakePHP because I hear it's a lot better.

However, after following the install instructions - I'm coming to this page. What did I do wrong? Looks like some kind of debugging page?
[image]

Comment: http://laravel.io/forum?tags=installation,configuration ?

Comment: What happens if you throw away all your cookies?

Comment: Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension. Is it installed?

Comment: @Theodore No I don't think I installed it.